# GWT - how to compile code to work on IE10

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, internet-explorer-10

Does GWT 2.5 supports ie10? 
If it does, what agent i should specify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GWT 2.5 does not have user agent specific to IE10 i.e No separate compiled permutation for IE10.

However, code compiled to work with IE9 will be able to function in IE10 as well. You need to pick up information on GWT 2.5 compatibility for IE9 here - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideIE9

**Note -**

1) To force IE10 in IE9 mode - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ie/hh920756(v=vs.85).aspx

2) More information on [MSDN IE 10 Compatibility Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

3) [GWT forum discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/hcLoOL3J4u4)

4) Track GWT Steering Committee [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/gwt-steering).

Comment: This question is whether objects such as ArrayBuffer (that supported only from IE10) will work?

Comment: Please update your question with this specific information. I do not think any direct support will exist. You would need to use JSNI support with Browser check currently to achieve this.

Comment: @ErikSapir: the answer is no: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.5.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/typedarrays/TypedArrays.gwt.xml Not out-of-the-box at least.

Comment: There are lots of differences between IE9 and IE10, it's not true to say that code compiled to work with IE9 will be able to function in IE10 too. My example is CSS filters, but I'm sure there's loads of them.

Comment: Yes there will be broken things. I mean functional in the sense you will be able to get the app running with few or no work arounds.

Comment: @SSR, that's irrelevant to me, I need to use IE10 features on my page when they're available too.

Comment: @mjaggard Note - that is the first line of the answer. There is no such permutation available and that seemed to be what erik needed to know. The only alternative is to have your own JSNI invocation to handle IE10.